# xmpp ejabberd online offline status issue when internet connection loss

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, ejabberd

I have ejabberd setup to be the xmpp server between mobile apps, ie. custom iPhone and Android app.But I've seemingly run into a limitation of the way ejabberd handles online status. 
      Assume there are two users A & B friends to each other and having current live chat conversation. Suppose one of them loss his internet connection then there is no way to instantly update his status to server. So his status remains online. 
      One solution to this problem is using mod_ping module in xmpp. But it's also have certain limitation, it will ping every clients after 32 seconds interval. So there is always 30 to 40 seconds delay in status update of user. 
      I want to update any user's status instantly (less than 10 seconds) in good network condition like what's up. This is very first scenario of chat app everyone face and i hope someone will help me through this.

Comment: Mod ping doesn't have delay of 32 seconds. Infact in smack I am using a timeout of 10s-15s and if no response received then I am declaring the offline. How did you came up with number 32 seconds?

Comment: hi thanks for comments , i'm personaly feel it while developement and all documents i refered on this also says the same . You can check it here https://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#modping

Comment: No this is server to client ping. In this case the server wait for 32s before declaring client offline. Then a presence will be broadcasted. Mind it that there are resume_time/max_resume_time (both default to 5 minutes) are also there so total delay will be 5min+32sec when you don't disconnect manually.  Client to client ping is  what you should try - https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.4/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/ping/PingManager.html#ping%28java.lang.String,%20long%29 .

Comment: i didn't understand mod_ping and resume_time/max_resume_time behaviour  clearly, i will take detail look on it's each functions, but is it help to resolved my problem?

Comment: Right if you want to make you app based on presence then it's impossible without draining user battery. Better idea is to use client to client ping but it is more of like a polling and not actual push.

Comment: Yes if i reduce ping interval time then there will be new problem arise regarding faster battery drain And therefore i'm looking for other alternatives. But I didn't get you on client to client ping or polling . i mean how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ejabberd upcoming 15.12 version you have a new `mod_ping` option: `ping_ack_timeout`. You can put whatever timeout you want.

This is already available in master branch, so you can already use it if you want: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd

Comment: Thanks Mickaël Rémond for letting me know, i will take detail look on it once it in market.

Comment: Hi Mickel , mod_ping option: ping_ack_timeout is also available in earlier version. So should  i prefered 15.11 or is there any better options are also availble regarding my problem in upcoming version 15.12

Comment: It is available in 15.11 but it is wrongly reported as an unknown option. It will work, so if you disregard that warning you should be fine.

Comment: Actually we are developing What's up kind of application. So, I think using latest version is best. So, is it good to go with beta 15.12 ? i mean it is stable or should we go with 15.11 and later on adopt to 15.12 whenever it release.